# Problem similar to midpoint theorem

Tags: geometry, triangles

I desperately need help solving the following problem. I made a sketch here:
[image]

In a triangle ABC, let:

- D $\in$ BC \ {B,C}
- E $\in$ AC \ {A,C}
- F intercepting point of AD and BE
- G intercepting point of AB and line through C and F

To prove:
AB || DE $\iff$ G is midpoint of AB

I'd really appreciate help on that one. I can't figure it out.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

Let use [Ceva's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem) and triangle similarity.

Answer (score 0):

If $DE$ is parallel to $AB$ then $\triangle ABD$ has equal area to $\triangle ABE$

$\triangle AEF$ has equal area to $\triangle BDF$

if we construct $PQ$ through $F$ and parallel to $AB, F$ is the midpoint of $PQ$

$\triangle ABC$ is similar to $\triangle PQC$

$G$ is the midpoint of $AB$